# How does "would" work in this context?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

> In American English the phrase "gone to hospital" **would** not be correct. One of the articles, "the" or "a", **would** be necessary.

What if I substitute "would" for "is"? Is there any difference?

> In American English the phrase "gone to hospital" **is** not correct. One of the articles, "the" or "a", **is** necessary.

Comment: The difference is that ***would*** is more "deferential / hesitant" than ***is*** in such contexts. If you like, you can think of it as implying something like *If you **were** to use it (but I expect someone as clever as you **wouldn't**), it would be incorrect*. Maybe not quite that "servile / ingratiating", but it's heading in that general direction. Alternatively you could imagine that it ***would*** be labelled "incorrect" ***after some debate*** (because not everyone will be immediately convinced; some may need time and discussion to explore the matter thoroughly).

Comment: So, "would" here shows openness to other suggestion, doesn't it? Also your sentence uses a conditional form. Can the type 2 conditonal form be used to make statements sounds hesitant/more deferential?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say "would" here shows openness to other suggestion. Just because a speaker shows "hesitant deference" in his phrasing of assertions doesn't necessarily imply anything at all about how strongly he *believes* those assertions (and thus how likely is it that the speaker might change their opinion). It just means that for whatever reason (often, because the addressee is of higher social status), the speaker doesn't want to make his assertion sound too dogmatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What ia the difference between "would" and "is" here? Life **would** be quieter without the telephone. Life **is** quieter without the telephone

Comment: In such contexts, ***would*** refers to something *counterfactual* (***if** we didn't have the telephone* - whereas in fact we ***do*** have phones). So your second example there, *Life **is** quieter without the telephone* would normally only be spoken by someone who doesn't have a phone (probably having given it up). It's possible (but fairly uncommon) for a speaker to use ***is*** there even if they and/or the addressee do have phones. Which arguably might carry the additional implication *It's perfectly common not to have a phone; even if you do have one, you know what it's like not to.*

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers. I get it now. By the way, in the sentence *Life is quieter without the telephobe* **would** normally only be spoken by someone who doesn't have a phone, you used "would", how does it work? Is "would" used for sometjibg counterfactual in your sentence?

Comment: Hello FumbleFingers. How does "would" work in thia sentence. A: What does "picture book goal" mean? B: Well, if something is ‘picture book’ it suggests that it is something very beautiful – maybe almost perfect – and so a ‘picturebook goal’ would be a beautiful goal. Is "would" indirect/less definited here?

Comment: I found [just one solitary instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+picture+book+goal%22) of ***a picture book goal*** in Google Books. Some sports commentators are notorious for coining "unusual" usages, but I think that one is best described as a "Malapropism" (the standard usage being [*a **textbook** goal*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+textbook+goal%22), with far more hits). So ***would*** there effectively means ***if it were in fact to be used** (but actually it rarely **is** used)*.

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers. **would** in this sentence is used for something less direct or less definite? For me Brexit **would** be a bad proposal --I'd lose business.

Comment: Note that *For me Brexit would be a bad proposal* is no longer a meaningful statement (on a par with *For me, being human would be interesting* - which makes no sense if the speaker ***is*** human).

Comment: Hello FumbleFingers Is "would" here the use of 'tentative' would?

We decided to look at how some of the UK press described this contender for goal of the tournament from Schick and so we’ll start with The Guardian who called it, ‘… a booming curler over the keeper’. The word ‘curler‘ describes the direction of the shot – the player curled or bent the ball over the keeper – while the word ‘booming‘ describes the power with which Schick hit the ball; a booming strike **would be** a really hard shot for example.

... a booming strike **would** be a really hard shot for example.

Comment: I don't think there's any particular implication of a "tentative" assertion in your example, no. It's just acknowledging that the expression isn't an idiomatically established usage with a known fixed meaning. Incidentally, I don't know how much of your text was verbatim from a Guardian hack, but in ***my*** opinion the (very unusual, "creative") collocation ***a booming shot*** here is nothing to do with loudness or hardness - it's alluding to [***a swinging boom arm***](https://www.definitions.net/definition/swinging-boom) ("arcing" across the pitch, like a cross by a winger).

Answer (score 0):

There's not really that much difference, although using their contraction form would sound more natural. However, *is* 'is' a much better word to use if you won't use their contraction form.

For example,

> In American English the phrase "gone to hospital" **would not/wouldn't** be correct. One of the articles, "the" or "a", would be necessary.

and

> In American English the phrase "gone to hospital" **is not/isn't** correct. One of the articles, "the" or "a", is necessary.

- Would is used to **communicate** about a **hypothetical or an imagined event**, and it is frequently employed when that prospective circumstance will or will not occur. While **is** *is* **classified** as a kind of verb where it **indicates occurrence or a state**, or rather just simply a **linking verb**.

Comment: I often see "would" used like this. My English grammar book says "would" is used to make statements sound less direct. What is "less direct?"

Comment: It's kind of synonymous with less certainty.

Comment: Well, uncertainty to be specific.

Comment: So, the use of would makes the speaker less definite about what they're saying, right? Use "is" is direct. I'm kind of confused. Could you explain?

Comment: Both can be direct, it depends on the sentence. For example your sentence. In American English, the phrase "gone to hospital" would not be correct. One of the articles, "the" or "a", would be necessary. If you read it, would sound direct and showed no uncertainty, but using is sounds much natural. Why? Well, it just really depends on the sound you hear while reading sentences including both of the words.

Comment: Well, it also depends on some rules of grammar.

Comment: It is incorrect when people say it OR It would be incorrect if someone were to say it.